# What is the term for someone who doesn't want to know?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a term for someone who is purposefully not learning information - usually bad information. Goes hand in hand with people who want to "hide their head in the sand" or have the "wool pulled over their eyes"

Comment: The expression is `bury one's head in the sand`

Comment: @Yohann V. 'The expression' seems to imply that that's the only variant used, but there are more Google hits for "hide his head in the sand" than for "bury his head in the sand".

Comment: Are you looking for a noun phrase, as that's the impression I get from your phrasing?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Haven't check google, by a little birdie told me... :'(

Comment: @Yohann V. 'A little birdie' is a very poor authority for saying something as critical as '_The_ expression is _bury_ one's head in the sand'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I should have moderated my sentence, sorry about this.

Comment: "troglodite" ..

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong with the other answers, but if you are looking for something more formal and/or legal, the term is "wilfully ignorant".

Comment: Dang it, I knew I shoulda hit the post button faster.  :-)  You beat me by 11 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

More like they don't want to "*see*" reality, i.e., the "grungier" aspects of life - there is the expression:

"He/She looks at the world through rose-colored glasses."

Answer (score 0):

There is :

> sweep problem under the carpet

*Fig. to hide or ignore something. "You made a mistake that you can't sweep under the carpet."*

If this person is refusing to learn the information because he is running away from this reality and his problems?

So maybe :

> *yellow-bellied* or *coward*

Answer (score 0):

I think the legal form of this is called **[plausible deniability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability)**.

You could also say that someone would want to remain oblivious.

Comment: "Plausible deniability" is where you know something, but nobody can prove you know it.

Comment: Touche.  I am not an attorney, but I did sleep at a Holiday Inn express last night.